# ¿Cómo detectar cambios en un objeto canvas de FabricJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Necesito detectar cambios en un objeto canvas de la librería [FabricJs](http://fabricjs.com/).

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {isDrawingMode:true});
//I need to watch the changes here -> 
canvas.toJSON();
```

He intentado usando esto [Object.prototype.watch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) de la siguiente manera:

> canvas.toJSON.watch('objects', function(){
>      //Hacer algo});

Pero no funciona, ¿alguien tiene idea de cómo resolver lo que necesito?

Comment: Bienvenido! Te invito a pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba utilizando el siguiente código:

```
var oldJSON = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON(['id']));
var newJSON = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON(['id']));
if(newJSON === oldJSON) {
    console.log('Equal');
} else {
    console.log('Not Equal');
}
```

Código sacado de la siguiente pregunta de SO, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851881/how-to-detect-changes-on-canvas-in-fabricjs).

Answer (score 1):

Para observar un objeto, ni `Object.observe` ni `Object.watch` son opciones validas pues están obsoletos o no implementados, lo que puedes hacer -de forma manual- es reemplazar cada una de las propiedades por un *getter* y un *setter* que cumpla la función de intermediario entre la propiedad en si y el usuario de la propiedad.

En este intermediario, invocas una función de callback, donde manejas el evento de cambio y puedas manipular el valor.

Este es un ejemplo de como hacerlo manualmente.

```js
var objeto = { propiedad: 1234 };

watch(objeto, "propiedad", function(prop, anterior, nuevo) {
  console.log(prop, anterior, nuevo);
  return nuevo;
});

objeto.propiedad = 9876;
objeto.propiedad = "abcd";

unwatch(objeto, "propiedad");

objeto.propiedad = "no sera observado";

function watch(objeto, propiedad, callback) {
  var valorAnterior = objeto[propiedad];
  var nuevoValor = valorAnterior
  
  function getter () {
    return nuevoValor;
  }
  
  function setter(val) {
    valorAnterior = nuevoValor;
 return nuevoValor = callback.call(objeto, propiedad, valorAnterior, val);
  }

  if (delete objeto[propiedad]) { 
    Object.defineProperty(objeto, propiedad, {
       get: getter,
       set: setter,
       enumerable: true,
       configurable: true
    });
  }
}

function unwatch(objeto, propiedad) {
  var val = objeto[propiedad];
  delete objeto[propiedad]; // eliminamos getter y setter
  objeto[propiedad] = val;
}
```

Nota final: mientras daba los últimos toques a esta respuesta, he visto la respuesta del @ElAsiduo y creo que para tu problema puntual es, posiblemente, una mejor solución que esta, si lo que quieres es saber si el objeto -como un todo- ha cambiado pero no te interesa saber que **propiedad especifica ha cambiado**; ya que este método no observa el objeto en profundidad (las propiedades internas del un array u objeto) sino que funciona superficialmente, sobre las propiedades "propias" del objeto en si. Para usarlo sobre todo un objeto deberías hacer watch sobre cada una de las propiedades y puede ser poco practico. Si necesitas un evento cuando cambia una propiedad, este método sera mas util. Saludos!